# Using Compare-Object in a script: where is my return value?

Tags: powershell, diff

I'm trying to write a powershell script which will do one thing if two text files are different, and another thing if the files are the same.

In Unix, I can just do `diff a.txt b.txt; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...`, but I'm having trouble programmatically determining whether two files are identical using `Compare-Object`.

My script so far is `Compare-Object (Get-Content a.txt) (Get-Content b.txt) -CaseSensitive`. `Compare-Object` seems to return `True` regardless of whether the files differ or not. How can I tell? Is `Compare-Object` not the tool for the job?

Comment: Keep in mind that by default `Compare-Object (Get-Content a.txt) (Get-Content b.txt)` does also match your files, if they contain the same lines, but in different sequence. (At least if they are not more than 5 lines away from each other.) To avoid such false negatives, use `-SyncWindow 0`.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Hmm, interesting. Any idea what the design decision was behind that? Why would someone want such a behaviour?

Comment: I guess the reason for this is that the field of application for `Compare-Object`is much wider than comparing text files. As `Get-Help Compare-Object` states, its job is basically to compare two sets of objects. Actually what you are doing in your example is a comparsion of two string arrays.  That sequence matters in this comparsion is just a special requirement of your scenario and therefore it makes sense, that it has to be explicitly stated. But frankly, I have not the faintest idea, why the default value for `-SyncWindow` would be 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run `Compare-Object` against two identical files (I used the same file in my test actually), it returns nothing, and if used in an `if` it will evaluate `$false`, and when there are differences it would evaluate to `$true`, so it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Wow, you're totally right. Not sure how I messed this up in my tests.

Comment: It's a real shame that MSDN doesn't just document this behaviour, though.

Comment: Honestly, they should just add a `-Quiet` switch like they do with `Test-Connection` that would give back a boolean value, and would stop immediately when it finds a difference (`Compare-Object` can be very slow).